# Android Add Firebase Crashlytics in Library Project

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics-android, firebase-crash-reporting

I am trying to configure Firebase Crashlytics in my library project. According to Firebase its not possible to configure Crashlytics in the library project.

I am getting this error message.

```
Crashlytics was applied to an android-library project.

Android-library support is currently an incubating feature.
```

Help me if you have any solution or workaround.

> I just wanted to log library project crashes in Firebase Crashlytics.

Comment: Do you intend to use it inside only your projects?

Comment: @МилошКојадиновић Yes, I am using that in multiple projects.

Comment: @AkhileshMani, can you share more details on why you want Crashlytics as part of library project, any benefit are you seeing here?

Comment: Currently only alternative is to implement firebase on your parent project and let your lib module accessing it

Comment: @Debu Yes, correct.

Comment: @MaulikHirani  We can get the crashes from parent applications. But the problem is to get the crash logs from the 3rd party parent application. Every time we have to reach them to get the crash logs.

Answer (score 3):

I recently worked on a library and from the get go, we knew that we won't be able to integrate an out of the box solution for this as it'll always conflict with consumer apps' implementation of the service like Firebase.

We opted for a different strategy. Handle all the crashes in the library ourselves and then heres what we do with them:

1. A listener set by the consumer app is notified of the error as a callback
2. Post the error logs to our own custom API server on next restart of the app and forward these logs onto different services like Firebase.

I understand this is not an exact solution that tells you how to use Firebase Crashlytics in a library but posting here as it gets the same work done.