# Using Firebase Crashlytics in SDK

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am working on SDK which uses react native. And I want to integrate Firebase crashlytics into my SDK. I was able to do it and I am using https://rnfirebase.io/ and all data are collected right. My `google-service.json` is in my SDK which is an "Android module" and it is working. But the problem is when I release my SDK to production or use `aar` file in another app. With simple integration, all data are collected to my Firebase space which is good but a problem starts when I am implementing Firebase into that simple project it will override my original `google-service.json` and all errors including errors from my SDK are collected in a new instance of firebase because it is init before my and I can not init another instance of firebase ... Any idea how to create two different instance of firebase or some alternative for collecting crashing for SDK?

Comment: Last I checked this was the expected behavior: Crashlytics reports issues to the app's project, not your library's project. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60946422/android-add-firebase-crashlytics-in-library-project, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828679/integrating-crashlytics-to-library-project (which seems to say it *can* be done), and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44394702/android-integrating-crashlytics-to-android-library-which-will-be-distributed-as (which was from the main authoritative source at the time).

Comment: Posts are 6y old and there is no way to do it... I was hoping there would be some way... thank you for the info